# Any way to "cut" background with the element?

Tags: css, background, cut

I need to cut an background of a div with a heading in the following way:

[image]

While it can be easily achieved on solid background (by setting element to inline-block and using same bg color as a main one), it doesn't really work when background is an image:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve same effect on second example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSS3 solution would be http://dabblet.com/gist/2788465 - it uses minimal markup and styling.

Another solution that also works in IE9 http://dabblet.com/gist/2788690

And another one that also works in IE7 and IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/Njtzb/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but you could do something like this:

Assuming HTML markup similar to this:

```
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='heading'>
    <span id='date'>May 20th, 2012</span>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

If the background of `outer` is the image, and the background of `heading` is the dotted line, you can set the `background-image` of the `span`s to be the same as `outer`, and then set the `background-position` to offset that image by the same amount as the element, so it lines up with the other background.